# How can I use TwigExtension from an existing symfony bundle?

Tags: dependency-injection, symfony-services

**UPDATED**

### Context

I'm using [Symfony Webpack Encore](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html) to take care of all the JS and CSS postprocessing, transpiling and so on...

There are different ways to implement webpack, even a module, [Webpack bundler](https://www.drupal.org/project/webpack) but Encore is really amazing.

I installed it via Yarn:  `yarn add @symfony/webpack-encore --dev`, it's working quite well, and smoothy integrates with theme libraries definitions.

### What I'd like to solve

Encore ships with a function, [`splitEntryChunks()`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/split-chunks.html) that analyzes files and split them into additional files to avoid duplication, assets big size...

Then in a Symfony app., you simply inject the build output in your templates with a couple of Twig extensions from WebpackEncoreBundle, whichever number of files, e.g

- for CSS :`{{ encore_entry_link_tags('app') }}`
- for JS : `{{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}`

If you don't use these Twig functions, you won't know how many files or even their names to link in the templates, so you unlikely will use `splitEntryChunks()`.

**This is why I'd like to use these Twig extensions in my Drupal templates.**

### What I've done so far

I added `symfony/webpack-encore-bundle` with composer (until then, only the JS part was installed with yarn), created a module and declared the class implementing the Twig extensions as a service.

I also had to take care of some services used in that class. `mymodule.services.yml` :

```
services:
  webpack.encore.twig.provider:
    class: Symfony\WebpackEncoreBundle\Twig\EntryFilesTwigExtension
    arguments:
      ['@service_container']
    tags:
      - { name: twig.extension }
  webpack_encore.tag_renderer:
    class: Symfony\WebpackEncoreBundle\Asset\TagRenderer
    tags:
      - { name: kernel.reset}
    arguments:
      ['@webpack_encore.entrypoint_lookup_collection', '@assets.packages']
  assets.packages:
    class: Symfony\Component\Asset\Packages
  webpack_encore.entrypoint_lookup_collection:
    class: Symfony\WebpackEncoreBundle\Asset\EntrypointLookupCollection
    arguments:
      ['@service_container']
```

At this point the twig extensions are implemented ! Yooooo....but I began to run in Webpack config issues, such as :

> The build _default is not configured in Symfony\WebpackEncoreBundle\Asset\EntrypointLookupCollection->getEntrypointLookup().

So I began to write a class to address these issues... but before diving in a debug session, I'm wondering if the whole approach makes sense.

### In a nutshell, is there a canonical and straightforward way to reuse Symfony Bundles in Drupal 8 ?

PS. I 've read that [@Kevin's answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/288351/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-a-symfony-bundle/288353#answer-288353) but was not inspired enough to follow these guide lines.

Comment: It looks like you need to use the tag twig.extension on the service. https://medium.com/@thihathit/extending-custom-twig-extension-to-drupal-8-twig-extension-class-d4b99c2177ae.  The first try in services.yml looks correct other than a bit of a deep indentation and missing tags.

Comment: You can't define classes inside of .module files. That should be in the `src/ServiceProvider` of your module with the proper namespace at the top.

Comment: @Kevin thanks it's a typo I ve just corrected the question. But I'm missing  the point,  shouldn't yml declaration be enough?

Comment: Is there a namespace in that file? Should be `Drupal\mymodule\Service;`

Comment: @Kevin my bad, I forgot mymodule in namespace, thanks ! So I have the service now, but I stil don't know how to use the methods from the injected class EntryFilesTwigExtension ?

Comment: Normally registering a new twig function is quite simple, but given that this is a Symfony bundle, I don't know if it will work quite the same: http://incurs.us/articles/extending-twig-drupal-8-add-your-own-filters